# How to remove this door knob?

Tags: lock, doorknob

It's stuck now. So I am trying to remove it to clean or replace.

Searched videos on youtube and didn't get any insight yet.

Any tips about how to remove this knob is appreciated!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the base you can see a little tab, visible at 9 o'clock in the first photo. Try pushing that tab all the way down and the knob should pull off when the tab is all the way down. If the tab doesn't move then the prior answer is most likely correct.

Answer (score 2):

On the inside door knob there is usually a small pin sometimes rectangular you need to press in that allows the inside knob to come off. Once the knob is off this will provide access to the screws. I would check the bolt/ latch these get bent and stick, I have just replaced the bolt/ latch on several doors for much less than an entire assembly.

Comment: Pulling off that trim piece behind the knob has inadvertently hidden the pin/slot used to remove the knob.